# How to get to a specifec node in firebase database real-time

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I got some messages key that was created by ChildByAutoID i am trying to access them or make the code read this keys to use this key somewhere else to get the some data from using this keys from firebase database

I tried to observe the UID of user to get keys but i can't get access to them as in code it show me the snap is the UID of user while iam trying to read nodes under the UID

in chat Controller

```
func sendMessage() {


    let currentUserID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("messages")
    let timestamp = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
    let text = typingMessageText.text as AnyObject
    let receiverid = user?.userid as AnyObject
    let senderid = currentUserID as AnyObject
    let time = timestamp as AnyObject
    let value: [String:AnyObject] = ["text": text, "receiverid": receiverid, "senderid": senderid, "timestamp": time]
    let childref = databaseRef.childByAutoId()
    childref.updateChildValues(value) { (error, myRef) in
    print(myRef.key as Any)
    let messageID = myRef.key
        let mnm = [messageID : 1]
    let userMessageRef = Database.database().reference().child("usersmesssages").child(currentUserID!)
        userMessageRef.updateChildValues(mnm)

    }
}
```

Observe function in tableview controller

```
func observeMessages(){
    let currentUserID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let newDB = Database.database().reference().child("usersmesssages").child(currentUserID!)
    newDB.observe(.value) { (DataSnapshot) in
    let key = DataSnapshot.key
        print("the Key is \(DataSnapshot)")
        let dbRef = Database.database().reference().child("messages").child(key)
        dbRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snap) in
            print("thesnap is \(snap)")
            if let dictinoary = snap.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                guard let receiverid = dictinoary["receiverid"] ,let senderid = dictinoary["senderid"], let text = dictinoary["text"], let time = dictinoary["timestamp"] else {
                    return
                }
                let messageValues = Message.init(text: text as? String, receiverid: receiverid as? String, senderid: senderid as? String, timestamp: time as? TimeInterval)
                self.messages.append(messageValues)
                dbRef.keepSynced(true)
                self.ChatRoomTable.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

[image: Firebase database Image]

**UPDATE**

```
print("the data is \(DataSnapshot)")
```

Result from it

```
the data is Snap (KxTbutCjzGQmIIb2OCGHrCyLNS53) {
"-LVx10-pBVxXTN-p88pT" = 1;
"-LVx10rtB0SL0y_mn4FU" = 1;
"-LVx4XosKZhkUDPgq0TI" = 1;
"-LVx4YT3NqYi1Tj12QFj" = 1;
"-LVx4_e8_OKwUrpAR_BM" = 1;
"-LVy2TEHGZD99ALhutbX" = 1;
"-LVy2dZB_mSIicC-qcSA" = 1;
"-LVy2xkg0oTT6bLbdC4T" = 1;
"-LVy3H6a__Tm_DKnM639" = 1;
}
```

How to access this nodes that (= 1) it self or save it to variables to use it.

Comment: What is the problem with the code you shared?

Comment: it don't work as i aspect i get this nodes

Comment: That's a bit broad. Keep in mind that Stack Overflow is an incredibly inefficient interactive debugger, so it's best if you do debugging yourself and let us know exactly what line of code doesn't do what you expect. Does the code inside the `observe(.value)` ever get executes? If so, does the code inside the `observe(.childAdded` get called too?